# How to associate an extension with a default program in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, registry

I have a little problem. Basically with Qt I saved an extension (example: .c--) in the registry editor with an icon with QSettings class. The only problem is that I would like to make sure that when you open this file with the extension (.c--) and it opens a software by default. I had never done this before in C ++ and after my research on the web I found nothing. So that's why I was wondering. Thank you for helping.

```cpp
QSettings  
reg("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\.c--\\DefaultIcon", 
QSettings::NativeFormat);
eg.setValue("Default", 
"path_to_icon");

//Code for open the .c-- extension with a program ?
```

Comment: "*after my research on the web I found nothing*" - MSDN had a whole chapter on this topic: [File Types and File Associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-intro), in particular look at [How to Register a File Type for a New Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-register-a-file-type-for-a-new-application) and [Registering a File Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-file-types#registering-a-file-type).

Comment: @Remy: To be fair to OP, Microsoft has been using the terminology of "Default Programs" rather than the correct technical term "File Association" for quite a few versions of Windows now.